# Trying to remember a fantasy book about a girl in a bottomless forest

Tags: story-identification, novel

Help!

I read this book when I was a kid, absolutely loved it, and though I can remember the feeling of reading it, remember nearly nothing about it!

It was some other world, where this society or village lived in a forest, high up in the trees. The main protagonist was a curious girl.

No one was allowed down to the bottom I think, or maybe someone was sacrificed and thrown down there sometimes? I just remember there being a dark secret about the bottom of the forest and she eventually goes down there. Also maybe there were blue lights in their village?

I know it's a really vague description but if anyone knows something like this, it would be amazing!

Thank you! x

Comment: http://comicsalliance.com/files/2012/05/saga03cover-1336680245.jpg

Genuinely thought you might be talking about Saga for a second...was thinking a bit too literally.

Comment: Sounds like Green Sky series, but unfortunately I haven't actually read it.

Comment: Was it just me who read the subject as being about a girl with no bottom in a forest? :O

Comment: @JaneS. That's a webcomic called *The Meek*.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds almost exactly like [*Below the Root.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A727126) The girl is teamed up with a boy with a sick little sister. They're part of a kind of priesthood. Everyone glides through the trees using special clothes & used to use something similar to the Force. And I think the blue lights are moths or some kind of creepy crawly.
If you read the illustrated version, the drawings are pretty distinctive, they might jog your memory.

[image]